# Can't access Cassandra remote node

Tags: remote, cassandra

I’m using cassandra on a remote node I can access just with console.
Since the node has a private ip, the cluster manager set a proxy to access private_ip:9042 in order to allow me to execute query against the db, so I have a public ip:port.

Unfortunately I’m not able to execute query and I’m investigate about why.

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /PUBLIC_IP:55092 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/PUBLIC_IP] Cannot connect))
```

I’m sure the procedure to execute the query is fine because I tried with an identical cassandra db developed on the localhost. I suppose the problem is in the listener set on the remote node.
Using Kafka I had a similar problem but I solved it setting a variable advertised_listener in the configurations file, specifying the public_ip:port I using to access to the node. Anyway I didn’t find anything of similar in cassandra.yaml file.

Do you know how can I solve the issue?

Thank you,
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

I solved setting broadcast_rpc_address in cassandra.yaml with the remote ip.